# Falha de comunicação com webservice PHP

Tags: php, c#, web-service

Estou tentando acessar um webservice PHP através de uma aplicação ASP.NET

```
ccbusca.pesqwebservice client = new ccbusca.pesqwebservice();
client.Url = "http://www.ccbusca.com.br/webservice.php";

ret = client.ws_pesqcpf("VISUALFIX01", "XXXX@", "302X");
```

Ao executar este trecho de código, estou recebendo este erro:

> Additional information: O cliente encontrou o tipo de conteúdo de
>   resposta de 'text/html; charset=UTF-8,text/xml; charset=UTF-8', mas
>   esperava 'text/xml'.

A resposta do webservice veio corretamente logo abaixo na mesma mensagem de erro.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ws_pesqcpfResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:cbuscaws"><return xsi:type="xsd:string"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <ocorrencia>
    <codocor>0</codocor>
    <msgocor>encontrado</msgocor>
  </ocorrencia>
  <cadastro>
    <cpf>XXX</cpf>
    <nome>OTAVIO</nome>
...
```

Tentei também fazer a requisição utilizando HttpWebRequest, mas sem sucesso.

```
string url = "http://www.ccbusca.com.br/webservice.php/ws_pesqcpf?usr=VISUALFIX01&pwd=visualfix2016@&cpf=30264304802";

            System.Net.WebRequest request;
            System.Net.WebResponse response;
            System.IO.Stream dataStream;
            System.IO.StreamReader reader;
            string responseFromServer;

            try
            {
                // Create a request for the URL.
                request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
                // If required by the server, set the credentials.
                request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                // Get the response.
                response = request.GetResponse();
                // Display the status.
                Console.WriteLine(((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                if(((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);
                    // Read the content.
                    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // Clean up the streams and the response.
                    reader.Close();
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                request = null;
                response = null;
                dataStream = null;
                reader = null;
            }
```

Desta maneira, eu não consegui visualizar os dados. Me retornou um código HTML de uma página que talvez seja uma mensagem padrão para erro 404.

URL Principal: http://www.ccbusca.com.br/webservice.php
Metodo: ws_pesqcpf
Parametros: usr, pwd e cpf

Sendo assim, minha URL não deveria ser esta?
http://www.ccbusca.com.br/webservice.php/ws_pesqcpf?usr=VISUALFIX&pwd=xxxx@&cpf=302X

Efetuando a consulta via SoapUI funciona. Consigo ver os dados.

Comment: O retorno parece estar errado do web service. De uma olhada em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115319/how-can-the-error-client-found-response-content-type-of-text-html-be-interp

Comment: @GabrielHeming não me parece que o erro seja do webservice, visto que  outras aplicações utilizam este webservice. Me parece que o retorno do webservice em PHP é realmente TEXT/HTML. Creio que nesta sircunstância deva utilizar HttpWebRequest para obter o retorno, mas ao tentar acessar, obtive erro 411.

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode acontecer quando o webservice gera um erro e ao invés de mandar em formato xml ele manda em formato html que seria a pagina com o erro. O client do webservice no .Net sempre espera uma resposta xml e se vier html ele lança esse erro. Ele controla isso pelo cabeçalho HTTP que tem o content-type que identifica o tipo de documento, se você utilizar alguma ferramenta pra interceptar essa mensagem http como o Fiddler por exemplo você consegue ver o pacote http da resposta e verá que o content-type está vindo como text/html.

Neste link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115319/how-can-the-error-client-found-response-content-type-of-text-html-be-interp tem uma explicação a respeito e pode ser que ajude.